# Google Drive Video Playback Link

Tags: google-drive-api

I don't really sure if this link is from google drive or not but the link like this

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=655d8adf2ea5cdd6&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1419332123&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=2FAA3FAB8E8753AFCC19CDDEC28AF30D4081E062.7330142E87D0587D6E85E8D898687F65956067F1&key=lh1
```

I see some website use these link to stream video presentation, and such, but how do they create these link to stream ?
is it some kind of api generated link ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a picasa video link

You can get that by seeking a video url from the picasa public url